# How do I overlay maps and add a shortest distance line from a polygon to a point?

Tags: r

I have a map of a shoreline and have added points to the map. I am trying to add a Shapefile containing a polygon outside the shoreline and then measure the shortest distance from the polygon to various points on the map. The map and an example point are below:

```
map(database="worldHires", xlim = c(-97.1, -80), ylim = c(25, 32.5), col = "grey", fill=TRUE,     lwd = 2, bg = "lightblue2", mar=rep(0, 4))
#add point
points(-90.0122, 29.2278, pch = 21, col = "blue", bg = "blue", cex=2)
```

I then want to add the Shapefile to the map, but when I try and do that I don't get an error message but it also does not show up as an addition to the map. Maybe I am using the wrong packages? I tried:

```
may <- readShapePoly("directory/satellite maps.shp")
plot(may, add=TRUE, col = "red")
```

I am new to R, so I apologize if this is elementary. After this problem is solved, I want to measure the shortest distance from the point in the map to the edge of the polygon. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Addition: I tried the following:

```
maptest <- readOGR("directory", "satellite maps")#Shapefile without extension
maptest1 <- transform(maptest, CRS("+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84"))
plot(maptest1)
```

where "maptest1" is the converted "may" from the above question. That did not work, the plot shows just two points, not the polygon. If I try to overlay "maptest1" onto the original shoreline map, I get several error messages about "add" not being a graphical parameter.

Comment: We can't debug this without your shapefile. I suspect `may` isn't in lat-long coordinates, or its just not in the right place. What does `bbox(may)` say? What does `summary(may)` say? Can you simply `plot(may)` and see something?

Comment: @Spacedman Thanks for the response!    bbox(may)    gives         min      max
x -10115725 -9552086
y   3115985  3441984.    summary(may)    gives    Object of class SpatialPolygonsDataFrame, same information as    bbox(may)    and some data attributes.    plot(may)    shows the polygon I want to overlay on the map.

Comment: Use `spTransform` from the `rgdal` package to convert coordinates. Check everything is the right type of object by calling `summary(...)`. Give us the shapefile if you want us to have a chance of sorting this.

Comment: @Spacedman, Thanks for the help!    spTransform    worked!